What symbolic or cultural significance does the fly buzzing around Ernest carry in "Killers of the Flower Moon"?
In Martin Scorsese's 2023 film Killers of the Flower Moon, a recurring motif caught my attention: a fly buzzing around Ernest Burkhart (portrayed by Leonardo DiCaprio) in certain pivotal scenes.
I distinctly noticed the fly's presence twice: first, when Ernest attempts to console Mollie as she is crying over her dead sister, and later, during the interrogation scene, where Ernest is being questioned by Bureau of Investigation agents. In both instances, Ernest swats at the insect with his hand. (I may have missed some other instances, so feel free to point those out too.)

A fly lands on Ernest's ear.

My initial interpretation leaned towards the fly's presence as a symbolic representation of Ernest's guilt and deceitful nature—a buzzing reminder of his misdeeds. However, given the film's weaving of Osage spiritual symbolism throughout—such as the owl signifying the impending arrival of death—I couldn't help but wonder if the fly holds deeper cultural significance within the context of Osage beliefs and traditions.
What is the symbolic or cultural significance of a fly being drawn to Ernest Burkhart in these scenes?

Maybe just that he's a piece of (scat). Flies are attracted to it.
